# XSP._isDirty() and/or enableModifiedFlag Does Not Work

Tags: xpages

Other posts refer to using XSP._isDirty() to trigger CSJS when form data has been changed and the user moves off of an XPage.   Doesn't seem to be working with Domino 9.0.1 FP1.    Earlier posts warned that it was a private function and may get removed.

Mastering XPages talks about using enableModifiedFlag for similar purpose (but this appears to be only for XPINC).

Any recommendations on how to warn a web browser user when they attempt to navigate away from an XPage that they will lose un-saved form data?

Comment: enableModifiedFlag works in browsers too. What have you tried since you say that it doesn't work?

Comment: @Per -  Thanks for your comment.   I just tested it with a database created with the R9 Discussion template with a web browser, and you are correct - the enableModifiedFlag gave an alert when trying to leave the page.  Not sure why it is not working on my own XPage, but I will keep digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use CSJS to fire an alert, when the user is going to close the tab / browse another URL / close browser

Use the `window.onbeforeunload` event where you can define a function which checks if the document is changed

Comment: thanks - How would you recommend tracking the original vs. changed values?  (because enableModifiedFlag is intended simplify that)