# XPages dirty forms - what am I missing

Tags: xpages

In an application I want to monitor if changes has occurred in input fields. Therefor I have added the following code to my XPage:

```
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptDirtyListener">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.attachDirtyUnloadListener("attention");

XSP.addOnLoad(function() {

XSP.attachDirtyListener("#{id:inpFirstName}");

}); ]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
```

but now when open the form, enter a value in my firstname field press refresh or navigate away no warning appears.

What am I doing incorrectly? Or does this only work with domino document data-binding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to trigger the code behind enableModifiedFlag from CCSJ or SSJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417149/is-there-any-way-to-trigger-the-code-behind-enablemodifiedflag-from-ccsj-or-ssjs)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10417149/is-there-any-way-to-trigger-the-code-behind-enablemodifiedflag-from-ccsj-or-ssjs/10428881#10428881 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370405/xsp-isdirty-and-or-enablemodifiedflag-does-not-work

Comment: Hej! That post is where I have got the idea from. But it does not work as expected. Take for example: XSP.attachDirtyUnloadListener("This document may contain unsaved changes."); The exakt content of the message will not be used but instead: Do you want to leave this site? Changes you made may not be saved.

Comment: I am seeing the same: XSP.attachDirtyUnloadListener(message) does not use the message

Comment: IE uses it, Chrome ignores it I have found out.

Comment: Did you check when you tap out of the field and then refresh? Also: add debugger; into your script and the Chrome debugger, when open, will stop the script, so you can inspect it in detail